# installing python package from a github subdirectory on another branch

Tags: pip

So I have a python package in a url which is something like this

```
https://github.com/my_profile/repo/tree/not_master_branch/folder_1/package
```

I know to install a package via pip it's:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@branch
```

but how do I specify the folders?

Answer (score 4):

```
python -m pip install 'git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@branch#subdirectory=folder_1/package'
```

***Reference***:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/?highlight=subdirectory#vcs-support

Comment: @tkxgoogle Does that answer your question? Any clarification needed?